# Ubuntu 20.04, PHP 7.4: mbstring installed but not enabled

Tags: ubuntu, php-7, mbstring

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and using PHP 7.4.

During a phpBB installation, it was reported "In order for phpBB to function correctly, the PHP mbstring extension needs to be available."  I was able to install it; `sudo apt list | grep mbstring` reports `php7.4-mbstring/focal,now 7.4.20-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [residual-config]`.

However, `phpinfo.php` reports `Multibyte decoding support using mbstring   disabled` in the `exif` section.  `phpinfo.php` also reports `Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`.

I edited this .ini file to uncomment `;extension=mbstring` in the Dynamic Extensions section, and restarted apache.  However, `phpinfo.php` still reports the extension is diabled.  I even rebooted the server, to no avail.  What am I missing?

Comment: OK, here's a clue - if I do a php -m and grep for mbstring, I get 

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/mbstring.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/mbstring.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: It turns out, mbstring.so is found in .../20200930, not 20190902.  Where is this path configured, so I can change it?

Answer (score 5):

Well, I guess the right package was *not* installed; this did the trick:  `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring`.  This delivered mbstring.so to the 20200930 directory, and phpinfo.php reports it enable.

Answer (score 1):

Install version specific package. For me i am using php 8.0.16 so i did this and it sorted me out `sudo apt-get install php8.0-mbstring`

Answer (score 0):

As you found out - the package was installed in the past but was erased (but not purged, so configuration files were left intact), this is indicated by `[residual-config]`.

Your setup will be more future proof by installing `php-mbstring` instead of `php7.4-mbstring` unless your use case requires this exact release. `php-mbstring` is just a dependency package the depends on the current release, so on 20.04 it installs `php7.4-mbstring` but when you'll upgrade to the next OS release it will be upgraded according to whichever php release will be shipped with it.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I was checking for php8.3 while the virtual host was running on php8.2